# Trocar diretório root do site com htaccess

Tags: php, html, htaccess

Como fazer para que quando uma pessoa acessar o site, o .htaccess reconhecer que o site está em `/site` ao invés de `/`, **/site** local onde onde conterá todos os arquivo do site. E quando for acessar a URL deve abrir `www.site.dev/` ao invés de `www.site.dev/site`

Imagem as pastas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Código que estou usando:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   Options All -Indexes

   # ROUTER WWW Redirect.
   # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
   # RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

   # ROUTER HTTPS Redirect
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

   # ROUTER URL Rewrite
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ site/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

### Já tentei:

```
RewriteRule (?!^site/)^(.*)$ /site/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !folder/
RewriteRule (.*) /site/$1 [L]
```

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez você esteja precisando disso:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews # Turn mod_rewrite on

RewriteEngine On RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/site/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/site/$1 -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/site/$1 -l
RewriteRule (?!^site/)^(.*)$ /site/$1 [R=302,L,NC]
```

Depois de verificar que está funcionando, troque o `R=302` para `R=301` na última linha.

Referência: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16513060/7970301

Comment: Lucius, havia conseguido dessa forma `RewriteRule ^ - [L]` `RewriteRule ^/?$ site/ [NC,L,QSA]` sabe me dizer se é um formato correto de se usar?

Comment: Seria interessante colocar o código 301 para "avisar" aos motores de busca que realmente se trata de algo permanente